# Specify destination for tarfile

Tags: python, backup, tar

Is there a way to specify where the tarfile needs to be created?

The script needs to make a backup from "/home" and should save it in "/backup"

My current code

```
  tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")
  tar.add(input)
  tar.close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am pretty sure you can use a path as argument instead of just the output_filename, like:

```
tar = tarfile.open("/backup/output_filename.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add(input)
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to make 'output_filename' be '/backup/output_filename' as this function takes the file path, not just the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Proper syntax would be:

```
tar = tarfile.open("/path/to/backup/output_filename.tar.gz", "w:gz")
tar.add("/path/to/home")
tar.close()
```

An mentioned above, the open function will take a path to the file you want to create. I recommend absolute paths so you can run this script from wherever.